# Sending real time buffer data between threads in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Lets suppose i have two fragments: FragA and FragB.

FragB is  inside FragA. In FragA, there is a rec button which when pressed will start a new thread(ThreadA) which will start recording audio using AudioRecord and save audio data to a buffer. In FragB there is another thread(ThreadB) which needs to consume buffer data from ThreadA in realtime.

How can i send buffer data from ThreadA to ThreadB in realtime ?

Comment: Producer-consumer queue of *buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pipe (in C it would mean looking at pipe(), mkfifo(), etc. I presume that Java has something similar). Write to the pipe in thread A, read from the pipe in thread B, and rely on the pipe's internal buffer to allow the two threads a degree of asyncronicity.

That's the lazy way of doing it, nor is it terribly efficient (the data is copied twice). But it is very simple to use.

Alternatively you could have a bunch of buffers, each protected by a pair of semaphores (you might call them 'filled' and 'emptied'). Thread A takes an 'emptied' semaphore, fills the buffer and posts the 'filled' semaphore. Meanwhile thread B is blocked trying to take the 'filled' semaphore, and when that unblocks it can then process the data then post the 'emptied' semaphore. Then move onto the next buffer. This is more efficient because the data isn't unnecessarily copied. There may be a Java class that pre packages all that for you, might have the word 'queue' in its name.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know where you have thread B.But if you want two threads to share same data buffer then you can make a class variable for buffer,and make two threads inside same class.This way they can use same buffer for reading and writing from different threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class with a data buffer in it which is instantiated when the app is started. This could be passed to both Frag A (and on to Thread A) and Frag B (and on to Thread B), one could fill the other could empty ...